# Django - download file from FileField()

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm struggling with the following problem. I have a database model with `FileField()`.

**models.py**

```
class InputSignal(models.Model):
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='signals/', null=False, )
```

A view that displays records from this table. It also supports deleting specific rows.

**views.py**

```
def storage_list(request):

    signals = InputSignal.objects.filter(author=request.user)

    if request.method == 'DELETE':

        id = json.loads(request.body)['id']
        signal = get_object_or_404(InputSignal, id=id)
        signal.delete()

        return HttpResponse('')

    else:

        return render(request, 'storage_list.html', {'signals': signals})
```

Template for this view looks like this:

**template.html**

```
{% for signal in signals %}
<li>
    <h4>{{ signal.name }}</h4>
    <p class="mb-0 pb-0">Date of addition:
      <b>{{ signal.add_date_pretty }}</b>
    </p>
    <p class="mb-1">Date of the last analysis: {{ signal.last_edit_date_pretty }}</p>
    <h6 class="mb-1">Adnotations:</h6>
    <p>{{ signal.adnotations | safe  | linebreaks | truncatewords:16 }}</p>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-3">Download</button>
    <button data-id="{{ signal.id }}" onclick='delteSignal(this)' class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

What I would like to do is to download the file in `signal.input_file` via the browser to the disk after clicking the 'Download' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{{ signal.input_file.url }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-3">Download</button></a>
```

you can use this for the download.