# How to download a file from FileField django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am building an application that should allow users to upload and download files using Django.

I have a model that stores files:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    unit_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    input = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.document.name)
```

I am able to display the list of uploaded files in my template from my view as such:

```
def Document(request, str):
    documents = Document.objects.filter(unit_code=str)
```

And in the template an anchor tag to download the file using the url as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467464/django-download-file-from-filefield):

```
{% for document in documents %}
    {{document.filename}}<a  href="{{document.input.url}}"> Download Document </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Right now I'm getting an error *page not found* (The url is directing to *127.0.0.1:8000/media/documents/file_name*

Is it possible to download the file using the anchor tag with the Django development server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings properly set, you need to add something like this to your urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You can read the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

**Important**: this solution is only good during development. For production your media files should be served directly from nginx (or whatever web server you are using) not through Django

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks for the production vs development tip as well; I know to be more careful serving files during production.